# Can I limit bean visibility by package in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, scope

Imagine I have the following structure (each level is in a different package)

OuterOuterService
--- OuterService
------ InnerService1
------ InnerService2

OuterService has dependency on InnerService1 and InnerService2.
OuterOuterService has dependency on OuterOuterService.

I want to prevent autowiring InnerService1/InnerService2 to the OuterOuterService.
I cannot make those protected, since OuterService uses them, and it is in a different package.
I cannot flatten the structure, because all of those services are actually packages with bunch of beans and own package hierarchy. Flattening a structure will cause chaos.

**Is it possible to prevent InnerServices to be autowired by OuterOuterService by any possible means (including restructurizing code)??**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

What about introducing a new class InnerServiceContainer which has package access to the InnerService 1 and 2 and provides protected methods to access them.

```
OuterOuterService
--- OuterService extends InnerServiceContainer
------ InnerServiceContainer
------ InnerService1
------ InnerService2
```

Comment: Indeed. The drawback is that I will stop to use Spring's autowiring, doesn't I?

Comment: Hmmm... No. Spring can autowire even to private property. Or you can use constructor autowire